# When is mormon.org going to be updated?

Tags: lds, prophets, name-of-jesus, internet, name

According to the new [Style Guide of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints](https://www.mormonnewsroom.org/style-guide), mormon should not be used to refer to the Church or its members, which mormon.org (which is owned by the Church) does in multiple places. Not only that, but the President Nelson has stated that this change is [doctrinally important](https://www.lds.org/general-conference/2018/10/the-correct-name-of-the-church?lang=eng).

So, when is mormon.org going to be updated to reflect this?

Comment: One could ask the same question about the [lds] tag here. Ah, [it's been done](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6617/16847).

Comment: Related: https://tech.lds.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=120&t=32402

Comment: It seems they already have ChurchOfJesusChristOfLatterdaySaints.com and .net redirecting to lds.org. Unfortunately, the .org redirected to the strangites in the past. They might be able to win access to that domain if they agreed to share with the five competing groups having a claim on it. I would consider that they have acted quite promptly so far.

Comment: @disciple who are strangites?

Comment: @p short answer: one of the other five. !w for Strang  James, and you will have the background to ask a well-focused question about them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

March 5th, 2019, the church [issued this:](https://www.mormonnewsroom.org/article/church-name-alignment?cid=email-OCA_Alignment_030519_CTA1)

> Websites: The Church’s official website will become
>   ChurchofJesusChrist.org. This change is effective today, March 5,
>   2019, when the domain name ChurchofJesusChrist.org begins pointing to
>   the LDS.org home page. In the coming months, the
>   ChurchofJesusChrist.org domain name will replace what were the
>   following:
>
> - LDS.org (ChurchofJesusChrist.org)
> - MormonNewsroom.org (Newsroom.ChurchofJesusChrist.org)
>
> Eventually, Mormon.org will be
>   incorporated into the new domain as well. However, because its primary
>   audience is those outside the Church, merging it with the Church
>   member-focused ChurchofJesusChrist.org will take more time.
>
> Work is underway to unify and restructure all these websites into a
>   new, more cohesive and personalized experience under the
>   ChurchofJesusChrist.org domain. Until that time, Mormon.org will
>   change to ComeuntoChrist.org.

So it will soon be ComeuntoChrist.org for a time, until it can be part of ChurchofJesusChrist.org.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe we know (yet).

As soon as possible?

President Nelson says:

> And some said it couldn’t be done, so why even try?
>
> ...
>
> It was the Savior Himself who said, “For thus shall my church be called in the last days, even The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints.”

So that's it: The Lord decreed that His Church will be called by that name in the last days, so it *will* happen, but the revelation from last conference does not seem to indicate a timeline. We will have to wait and see (and do our part as members).

It's likely not just mormon.org that will have to change, but probably Mormon Newsroom, lds.org, and several other significant Church-owned assets.

Comment: Mormon Newsroom has already been renamed (although it still has the same domain).

Comment: @Matt - Where did Jesus say his church would be called 'The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints"?  Can you please provide the source/reference?

Comment: @Lesley you could probably ask that in another question

Comment: @Lesley If you click on the first link in the Question, and from there the first link, the information is revealed that Jesus gave the information in Missouri in 1838.

Comment: Found the information in the official link below - seems Joseph Smith was given the name by divine revelation in 1838: https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/115.3-4#2

Comment: The "Mormon Tabernacle Choir" has also been renamed (as of a week ago), to "The Tabernacle Choir at Temple Square." Changes to other apps and websites are coming.

Answer (score 3):

Mormon Newsroom [issued the following statement](https://www.mormonnewsroom.org/article/why-is-newsroom-still-mormon-newsroom) on 16 October 2018:

> ...Church websites and materials will be updated in coming weeks and months. President Nelson and other Church leaders understand that a change this significant requires careful consideration, coordination and planning. Newsroom, like other Church channels, is following the counsel of Church leadership regarding the direction and timing of changes to MormonNewsroom.org.

So, the answer to your question is "in coming weeks and months."  Unfortunately, nothing specific, but the change will happen, it's just being done with prudence and consideration and thus is taking time.

(Mormon Newsroom itself is currently in between calling itself "Newsroom" and "Mormon Newsroom".  Some parts of the website have converted over, others haven't.)

Answer (score 0):

It'll likely be a rolling release over the next few months of certain parts of the church's PR and infrastructure being changed. Do they want to change it? Yes. Are Internet domains and a myriad of other nomenclature in a multimillion-person worldwide church also a thing? Yes. Even if it's a swift change it will take some time due to the nature and size of the organization.

Mind you, The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints has always been the correct and preferred name. This new Style Guide is basically ruling out nicknames, not making an actual name change. The actual name's never really changed since 1830.

Comment: Don't forget the hyphen between "Latter" and "Day" (day should be lower case with the hyphen)